# Net C# Date Time conversion

Tags: c#

I would like to convert date as below:

"**Friday, November 2 2018 6:12 PM**"

To

"**20181102|18:12**"

Appreciate it.

My coding as below, and show string was not recognized as valid datetime. Anyone can help me out?

```
String DateCv_01 = dtB.Rows[i_01]["APi_Time"].ToString();

DateTime DateCv_02 = DateTime.ParseExact(DateCv_01.ToString(), "dddd, MMMM dd yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string DateCv_03 = DateCv_02.ToString("yyyyMMdd|hh:mm");
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should use `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert the string to a `DateTime`. Then use `ToString` with the appropriate format string to convert it back to a string in the desired format. I suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings, try to implement it yourself, and then edit your question with what you've tried and what went wrong if you get stuck.

Comment: Okay, your question is getting better - but "but error" doesn't give us enough information to help you.

Comment: @AccessDenied: I wouldn't worry about that: I'd specify the invariant culture instead (otherwise the year etc may be unexpected too). More importantly, it should be `HH` instead of `hh`.

Comment: "My coding as below but error" - what is the error? Does it not compile? Return the wrong thing? Reformat your hard drive? "Error" covers a broad range of things and you shouldn't leave us guessing!

Comment: I realise we're all trying to be nice now, but how does this have 3 upvotes?

Comment: You are almost done it. Try to use only on `d` and `h` in your format. `dddd, MMMM d yyyy h:mm tt`

Comment: Ad your input has only one digit for the day and the hour, you should use the format string "dddd, MMMM d yyyy h:mm tt"

Comment: What is the *real* type of `dtB.Rows[i_01]["APi_Time"]`, before you convert it to string? If it already is a DateTime, then *cast* to a DateTime

Comment: About `DateCv_01.ToString()`, that `DateCv_01` is *already* a string, so you don't need that `.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

Following is the usage of days and hours:

[image]

Which means following datetime format should be used:

`dddd, MMMM d yyyy h:mm tt`

Try below code:

```
DateTime DateCv_02 = DateTime.ParseExact("Friday, November 2 2018 6:12 PM", "dddd, MMMM d yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string DateCv_03 = DateCv_02.ToString("yyyyMMdd|hh:mm");
```

Comment: How you answered to a closed question?

Comment: @SeM likely answered before it was put on hold...he's Batman but he's not that magic :-)

Comment: @FaizanRabbani hm, ok then :)

Comment: @ADyson When I asked, he have answered about 3 min ago, but question was put on hold about 10-15 minutes ago, so it was kind of strange (or maybe I didn't noticed that question has an answer, but I was pretty sure it doesn't) :)